# Probability of getting exactly 2 items from the same group in a collection of different groups of items

Tags: probability

There are 4 boxes: a box that contains red rabbits, yellow rabbits, orange rabbits and purple rabbits. Each box contains more than 6 rabbits in each of the four boxes (so you never run out of "picks"). You choose a rabbit from a random box 6 times.

What is the probability of getting exactly 2 red rabbits?

I tried the following method: there is 1/4 probability of choosing a red rabbit so I did and a 3/4 probability of choosing something else (1/4 * 1/4 * 3/4 * 3/4 * 3/4 * 3/4) * number of ways you get to choose the red rabbits = (.25)^2 * (3/4)^4 * comb of 6, take 2. I got 0.296, which seems to be wrong?

Comment: What makes you think that this is incorrect?

Comment: This is not clear.  Are all the boxes the same?  how many of each color does each box contain?

Comment: All boxes contain the same number of rabbits - just assume you'll never run out of rabbits to choose from a box

Comment: @lulu my interpretation (*and the OP's apparent interpretation given his answer*) is that each box contains a single color with an unlimited number of rabbits of the corresponding color.  Each time a rabbit is drawn he picks a box uniformly and independently at random.  Reworded, he is rolling a $d4$ six times and counting the number of occurrences of having rolled the number $1$.

Comment: @JMoravitz  Oh, thank you.  That makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried the following method: there is 1/4 probability of choosing a red rabbit so I did and a 3/4 probability of choosing something else (1/4 * 1/4 * 3/4 * 3/4 * 3/4 * 3/4) * number of ways you get to choose the red rabbits = (.25)^2 * (3/4)^4 * comb of 6, take 2. I got 0.296, which seems to be wrong?

Yes.

If we say a trial is selecting a box, and a success is selecting the red rabbit box, then you have six independent Bernoulli trials with identical success rate $1/4$.   The count of red rabbits selected is Binomially distributed, $\mathcal{Bin}(6,\tfrac 14)$.

Then ${(\tfrac 14)}^2{(\tfrac 34)}^4\binom 62$, $\tfrac{1215}{4096},$ or $0.296630859375$ is correct.   Why do you think it is not?

Comment: It's a homework assignment, I've already tried this very answer but it seems to be incorrect. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with this method.

Comment: @Gabe It *is* correct.  You are not going wrong.  Unless you are being deducted points for rounding down.  The answer to three decimal places is $0.297$.

Comment: It's gotta be 4 decimals so I said 0.2966

Comment: Then indeed it is $0.2966$.   If you are answering an online questionnaire, then *it* has the wrong answer, rather than you.

Comment: It's apparently a stars and bars problem

Comment: Not the way you have presented it.